# Backing up important files in a remote location

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, backup

I run a small home office with the main pc running Windows 7 and i would like to back up my essential files, as is good protocol.

I intend to hook up an old laptop running windows xp to an external harddrive, and would like to send the files i wish to back up periodically to this hard drive. I may store this laptop in the home network but in a different room, or in a separate building and access it over the net.

I would prefer to store my data on a physical harddrive that i have access to as opposed to using dropbox etc...

Could any one offer any advice as to achieving the above, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Noel

Comment: Just create a shared network folder on the laptop, mount it permanently in your machine that you want to backup and then use the [Windows 7 Backup and Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/backup-and-restore) feature. Apart from that: Be more specific to which version of Windows you're using where, because not all of the above features are available on all versions.

Comment: @slhck edited my question to include the operating systems, will take a look at windows 7 backup and restore, cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CrashPlan](http://www.crashplan.com/) can do what you want.  You can install the free version on two PCs and backup from one to the other.  The free version will automatically back up once a day, but you can run it manually whenever you want.  You can plug the notebook PC into your LAN for a quick initial backup, then move it offsite for ongoing incrementals.

Comment: Cheers for the advice, have installed crashplan and all seems to be going well thus far.